flutter media kit error when building for linux
i am building a video player for Linux (ubuntu) using flutter and media kit ,got an error , i have installed  pkg-config and mpv in my system the log given below.
CMake Error at flutter/ephemeral/.plugin_symlinks/media_kit_video/linux/CMakeLists.txt:16 (add_library):
Target "media_kit_video_plugin" links to target "PkgConfig::mpv" but the
target was not found.  Perhaps a find_package() call is missing for an
IMPORTED target, or an ALIAS target is missing?
CMake Generate step failed.  Build files cannot be regenerated correctly.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
